# Sum of arithmetic series and geometric sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sum of first 7 arithmetic sum is 28.
Sum of their squared values are 812.
What's the increment/difference (a) of first sequence?

```
Sn = 1/2 * n * (a + Un)
S7 = 7/2 * (a + U7)
28 * 2/7 = (a + U7)
8 = a + U7
```

then the second one

```
Sn = U1 * (1- r^n) / (1-r)
S7 = U1 * (1 - a^7) / (1-a)
812 = U1 * (1 - a^7) / (1-a)
812 = U1 * (1 - (8-U7)^7) / (1-(8-U7))
```

I don't know how to solve this '__') asking for a friend

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  The sum of the numbers from $1$ to $7$ is indeed $28$.  The sum of what squares is $812?$  The sum of the first $13$ squares is $819$, which is close.  Which is the first sequence you are referring to?  It would seem to be $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ with increment $1$.  Please clarify.

Comment: it's not defined that the start and the end value is any number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that $a_7=a_1+6d$ where $d$ is the difference between consecutive members.

Then $S_7=\frac{a_1+a_1+6d}{2}\cdot 7=28$ or $a_1+3d=4$, $a_1=4-3d$.

Sum of squares of the first seven members: $$(4-3d)^2+(4-2d)^2+(4-d)^2+4^2+(4+d)^2+(4+2d)^2+(4+3d)^2=7 \cdot 4^2+d^2(9+4+1+1+4+9)=112+28d=812 \rightarrow d^2=25 \rightarrow d=\pm5$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^6(a+kd)
&=7a+\frac{d}{2}(6)(6+1)\\
&=7a+21d\\
&=7(a+3d)=28\\
&a+3d=4\\
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^6(a+kd)^2
&=\sum_{k=0}^6(a^2+2adk+d^2k^2)\\
&=7a^2+\frac{2ad}{2}(6)(6+1)+\frac{d^2}{6}(6)(6+1)(2(6)+1)\\
&=7a^2+42ad+91d^2\\
&=7(a^2+6ad+13d^2)=812\\
&a^2+6ad+13d^2=116\\
\end{align}$$
Using the first equation
$$(a+3d)^2=4^2$$
$$a^2+6ad+9d^2=16$$
So subtracting this from the latter equation gives
$$4d^2=100$$
$$d^2=25$$
$$d=\pm5$$
$$a=4-3d\implies a=-11,19$$

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from my other friend (in this case, b is the difference/increment, a is the initial number)

```
Sn = n/2 (2a+(n-1)b)
S7 = 7/2 (2a+6b)
28 = 7/2 (2(a+3b) 
4 = a + 3b 
a = 4 - 3b

U1^2 + U2^2 + ... + U7^2 = 812
a^2 + (a+b)^2 + ... + (a+6b)^2 = 812
7a^2 + 42ab + 91b^2 = 812 
a^2 + 6ab + 13b^2 = 116
```

susbstitute a with above [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+%3D+4+-+3b;+a%5E2+%2B+6ab+%2B+13b%5E2+%3D+116)

```
4b^2 = 100
b^2=25
b = 5
```